# Make whole page non-interactive except for one element

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I make a webpage completely non-interactive to the user, but make one div (or other element) interactive?

Comment: You could put a element over the entire screen, then position it above all other elements to prevent mouse clicks, then on top of that add the element you want to allow. This would be easy to get around though if someone knows how to use the console. Why do you need this out of curiosity?

Comment: Edited to change the term "responsive" to "interactive" as "responsive" has a different meaning in front end development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with CSS only using [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). Set `pointer-events: none` on the `body`. Set `pointer-events: auto` on the target element.

```js
var buttons = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button'), 0);

buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('responds');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.respond {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<button>I don't respond</button>

<div>
  <button class="respond">I respond</button>

  <button>I don't respond</button>

  <button>I don't respond</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#blocker {
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    top:0;
    left:0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.allow {
    position:absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    top:50%;
    left:50%;

    background:red;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>
content to block
</p>
<div id="blocker">

</div>
<div class="allow">


<p>
Content to allow
</p>
</div>
```